# VS2017/VB.NET: Assign an Enum Count to Constant

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cannot assign Enum...length to constant

```
Public Const myConst As UShort = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(myEnum)).Length
```

Error: gives an error "Constant expression is required."

I have alternative strategies so getting the desired effect is not the issue.
[Although if anyone knows how to get the value directly from the enum into a constant rather than creating a read-only property, that would be marvelous. I don't want a manual count of enum values and then hard-coding the total into a constant.]

But I am merely curious why this expression is not valid VB. I would think that the length of an enum is fixed at compile-time (is it?) and hence would be a legitimate RHS of a const statement?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't assign a value that has to be calculated at run time to a constant. the value must be known at compile time. In theory, that `Enum` could be in a different DLL that you could replace and so your constant could have two different values between two sessions.

Comment: jmcilhinney is right. The enum is fixed but the way you get the length is a calculated field at runtime. An other option would be to set it as readonly instead of const.

Comment: Thanks Chaps. I thought the enum size was a compile time calculation, not a runtime calculation. What you say makes sense! Rgds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length need to be calculated at runtime, especially since GetName is executed at runtime.

I would suggest you use ReadOnly instead.

```
Public ReadOnly myConst As UShort = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(myEnum)).Length
```

If you need it shared, it's also possible

```
Public Shared ReadOnly myConst As UShort = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(myEnum)).Length
```

Also, I think you have Option Strict Off since .Length is an Integer. I would strongly suggest you turn it on.

Comment: Thank you Lotus! Helpful stuff. Much appreciated.